# React app shows a blank page after deployment to github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, react-router-dom, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my portfolio website to github pages but after deployment it shows a blank page

You can find the repository at : [here](https://github.com/oneknucklehead/oneknucklehead.github.io)

I have tried adding base name to BrowserRouter and stuff, but it still doesn't work.

below is the package.json extract:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://oneknucklehead.github.io/oneknucklehead.github.io/",
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2",
    "react-use": "^17.2.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.18.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Check your `homepage` on the package.json

Comment: Please add `package.json`

Comment: Hey @RyanLe! I've already added the homepage on package.json.
I've also re-edited the question with the package.json extract.

Comment: Hey @Danial! The package.json file is already there in the repo

Comment: Check that string, it's not looking fine to me.

Comment: I've kept the homepage string like that so that the portfolio directly opens at https://oneknucklehead.github.io

Comment: @ZohebAhmed Could you try `"homepage": "."`

Comment: @Danial didn't get you, can you explain a bit?

Comment: `"homepage": "."` does address all files relative to `index.html` @ZohebAhmed

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!
I figured out that in the scripts part, instead of "deploy":"gh-pages -d build" it should be "deploy":"gh-pages -b master -d build"